# Revisiting Excel parsing

Tags: string, excel, parsing, excel-formula

I have gone through the variations on these and each has a different solution depending on how the names are in a cell. Let me make it clear. I have an excel sheet containing the names of my colleagues from my college days. The names are in no particular format. The "Name" column has the names like:

1) Dipak C. Chopra
2) Amar D Pathak
3) Lara Naik
4) Reshma Laxman Bhavsar

So as can be seen, some have simply a middle initial, some have it with a period and some have it missing while some have a full middle name. What I wish to do is to rewrite these names in another column by last name so that it turns out like:

1) Chopra Dipak C.
2) Pathak Amar D
3) Naik Lara
4) Bhavsar Reshma Laxman

I can do it but I have to use formulae with variations depending the name in the cell: e.g.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(" ",B2)) & " " & LEFT(B2,FIND(" ",B2))) for the 3rd entry
=TRIM(RIGHT(B4,LEN(B4)-FIND(" ",B4)-1) & " " & LEFT(B4,FIND(" ",B4)+1)) for the 2nd entry     
=TRIM(RIGHT(B13,LEN(B13)-FIND(" ",B13,FIND(" ",B13)+1))&" "&LEFT(B13,FIND(" ",B13,FIND(" ",B13)+1))) for the 4th entry.
```

My question is how can I revise this formula to give me the desired result in all the cases mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",B2)),B2,RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","~",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","")))))&" "&LEFT(B2,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","~",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))))-1))
```

It involves doing a reverse string search to find the last space and then uses its position to cut the last name off and then add on the rest of the string to the end,  if there is no spaces in the string it will just return the value is B2

Beautified

```
   =IF(
    ISERROR(
        FIND(
            " ",
            B2
        )
    ),
    B2,
    RIGHT(
        B2,
        LEN(
            B2
        ) -
        FIND(
            "~",
            SUBSTITUTE(
                B2,
                " ",
                "~",
                LEN(
                    B2
                ) -
                LEN(
                    SUBSTITUTE(
                        B2,
                        " ",
                        ""
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) & " " &
    LEFT(
        B2,
        FIND(
            "~",
            SUBSTITUTE(
                B2,
                " ",
                "~",
                LEN(
                    B2
                ) -
                LEN(
                    SUBSTITUTE(
                        B2,
                        " ",
                        ""
                    )
                )
            )
        ) - 1
    )
)
```

Comment: That's perfect, Steven Martin. I was thinking about that idea but didn't know how to go about it. I had done it previously but using VB code. Your excel formula works beautifully.